# Java Programming real objects

Tags: java, swing, camera

I never programmed real objects. I only did some JFrame, Swing and a little bit of game Engines.
I've always wondered, is it possible to program real objects? like a web camera Board? if yes, then how? Especially a web camera, how is that possible?

I have a school project about web cameras and I thought on and said to myself, why not program the board to make it more advanced!

The main question is: Can I program real life objects (like a webcam), and how?

Comment: What are *real* objects? Are there *fake* ones?

Comment: You can't program "real" objects. You will have to use your hand to move them around.

Comment: What do you mean by "program real life objects"? A computer screen is a "real object" and we all (perhaps indirectly) program that.

Comment: Are you talking about [Image Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_processing)?

Comment: uhm objects like ... a microphone? a webcam's microphone.. that kind of stuff

Comment: @MarounMaroun Sure. Mockito.

Comment: @chrylis They *are* real, but fake ;)

Comment: If you more want to control some hardware (sensors, camera, motors, ... instead of writing a firmware for it) you might also have a look on Java ME 8 embedded (http://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.0/index.html) and Tinkerforge (http://www.tinkerforge.com/en/home/what_is_tinkerforge/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.  Unfortunately Java is not well suited for this task (for various reasons).

I would suggest you buy an arduino set and learn what it can do regarding controlling devices and receiving input from sensors, so you know more about what is possible.

Comment: Thank you for that answer! but another question if possible.. is that Arduino board.. programmable in Java? what type of programming level does it need?

Comment: No.  The Arduino boards are too small for Java, and are programmed in a C dialect.  C, however, looks a lot like Java (except for there is no objects) so it is relatively easy to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean if it is possible to create a firmware or program embedded systems in Java. Answering this question is not so easy. If the producer of the "real object" provides you a way, how to create a programs for that real object, then yes, it is possible, but this is quite rare. You can't just buy the cheapest web camera and write your own firmware. Google up some programmable devices, that you can fiddle with or if you are just curious and this is you hobby, then make an application for a smartphone. Android devices are programmed in Java and you can play also with the camera.